# Create Windows USB Stick from DVD

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, windows-installation, installation-media

I have

- a Win7 PC with a Windows 8.1 DVD in the drive and an ISO I made from that DVD on the hd.
- an empty pen drive of 8G
- an Ultrabook, on which to install Win 8.1
- a 56k Modem connection
- no USB DVD drive is available.

I found the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool, which can install a Win7 ISO on a pen drive, and I found the Windows 8.1 Setup Tool, which can download 8.1, and possibly put it on a pendrive (not sure about that).

But how can I create a bootable pen drive from my 8.1 DVD or ISO, so that I can start installing today? (the download would need days, I guess)

Comment: Did you try using the official Windows 7 USB/DVD tool? It should work just fine. As an alternative you can use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: The official Windows 7 USB/DVD tool always told me that the ISO is not valid. We now solved it by asking a neighbor for a portable DVD drive.